# How to create a Monte Carlo function that simulates the consistency of the beta estimator?

Tags: r, statistics, montecarlo

I'm having some problems with my custom function. The main idea is that I want to show that the beta estimator gets closer to 1 as I increase the number of observations. So I wrote this custom function and tried it for n = 200 and n = 1000. The problem is that changing the number of observations doesn't do anything as far as I can tell. Any input is highly appreciated!

My guess is that I've coded my function badly (as opposed to some statistical error).

Here's the function:

```
func <- function(iterations, observations){
  set.seed(1001)

  betas <-c()
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    c <- 1:observations
    x <- c/5
    e <- rnorm(1)*x # Remove x if you want homoskedastic errors
    y <- x - 10 + e
    #y[y < 0] <- 0 # censoring
    model <- lm(y ~ x)
    betas[i] <- model$coefficients[2]
    
    #name:
    arg_name <- deparse(substitute(observations))
    var_name <- paste("obs", arg_name, sep="_") # Construct the name
    assign(var_name, betas, env=.GlobalEnv) # Assign values to variable
    # variable will be created in .GlobalEnv 

  }
}
```

Use it with different number of observations:

```
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 200)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 1000)
mean(obs_200);mean(obs_1000) # Compare means
```

Plot data

```
library(ggplot2)

# Make individual data frames
a <- data.frame(group = "a", value = obs_200)
b <- data.frame(group = "b", value = obs_1000)

# Combine into one long data frame
plot_data <- rbind(a, b)

# plot

ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = group,
                   y = value,
                   fill = group))
```

**EDIT**

```
library(tidyverse)

func <- function(iterations, observations){
  set.seed(1001)
  
  betas <-c()
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    c <- 1:observations
    x <- c/5
    e <- rnorm(observations)*x # Remove x if you want homoskedastic errors
    y <- x - 10 + e
    #y[y < 0] <- 0 # censoring
    model <- lm(y ~ x)
    betas[i] <- model$coefficients[2]
  }
    #name:
    arg_name <- deparse(substitute(observations))
    var_name <- paste("obs", arg_name, sep="_") # Construct the name
    assign(var_name, betas, env=.GlobalEnv) # Assign values to variable
    # variable will be created in .GlobalEnv 
    
  
}


func(iterations = 2000, observations = 200)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 400)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 600)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 800)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 1000)
mean(obs_200);mean(obs_1000) # compare means

# Make individual data frames
plot_data <- tibble(a = obs_200,
       b = obs_400,
       c = obs_600,
       d = obs_800,
       e = obs_1000) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "n")


# plot

ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = n,
                   y = value,
                   fill = n)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.5, labels = c("200", "400", "600", "800", "1000")) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = NULL, 
       y = NULL, 
       fill = "Observations",
       title = "Monte Carlo simulation using OLS",
       subtitle = "(Heterosedastic errors)")
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you want `e <- rnorm(observations) * x`. (Also, avoid side effect, i.e., `assign`. Have your function return the result and do `obs_200 <- func(iterations = 2000, observations = 200)`.)

Comment: @Roland . I think thats it. Will get back when Im home...

Comment: Side note:  avoid using "c" as a variable name. While it usually won't cause "confusion" with the function `c`,  bad things can happen.  I wouldn't use "e" either, since  someday it might foul up something like `1.2e5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues:

1. `e <- rnorm(1)*x` means all of the error are correlated. Use `e <- rnorm(observations)*x` instead.
2. Variables should be saved outside of for loop.
3. Since the error term is not constant. Weighted Least Square is more suitable.
4. n=200 and 1000 would not make huge difference. Try larger difference instead.

Code:

```
func <- function(iterations, observations){
  set.seed(1001)
  
  betas <-c()
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    c <- 1:observations
    x <- c/5
    e <- rnorm(observations)*x # Remove x if you want homoskedastic errors
    y <- x - 10 + e
    #y[y < 0] <- 0 # censoring
    model <- lm(y ~ x,weights=x)
    betas[i] <- model$coefficients[2]
    
    
    
  }
  #name:
  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(observations))
  var_name <- paste("obs", arg_name, sep="_") # Construct the name
  assign(var_name, betas, env=.GlobalEnv) # Assign values to variable
  # variable will be created in .GlobalEnv 
}
```

Testing:

```
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 1000)
func(iterations = 2000, observations = 10000)
mean(obs_1000)
[1] 1.00306
mean(obs_10000)
[1] 0.9989306
var(obs_1000)
[1] 0.01282296
var(obs_10000)
[1] 0.00123895
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my original post. I did not add weight as I wanted to test the consistency of the estimator without additions (but thanks anyways!). It seems that going from 200 to 1000 does quite a bit! I will mark your answer as the solution unless you want to add something to my edit?

Comment: Looks good! I like the plot you generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to run a montecarlo simulation through different values. I send here the code that I used for my econometrics term paper, you can change it with the parameter that you need really easily. Sorry if I avoid going in the specific of your code but I guess you are still trying to see what you want to do with it so starting from a base code like mine could be helpful for you

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)

n_vec <- c(100, 500, 1000)
rho_vec <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9)
beta2_vec <- c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

results <- list()

for (n in n_vec) {
  for (rho in rho_vec) {
    for (beta2 in beta2_vec) {
      
      # set other parameters
      beta1 <- 0
      cov_mat <- matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), nrow = 2)
      k <- 1000
      
      # placeholder for current iteration results
      iter_result <- list()
      
      # run Monte Carlo simulations
      b1 <- numeric(k)
      b2 <- numeric(k)
      short_b1 <- numeric(k)
      test1 <- numeric(k)
      test2 <- numeric(k)
      test3 <- numeric(k)
      for (i in 1:k) {
        data <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = cov_mat))
        names(data) <- c("X1", "X2")
        data$Y <- beta1 * data$X1 + beta2 * data$X2 + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
        
        # long model
        reg <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data)
        b1[i] <- coef(reg)["X1"]
        b2[i] <- coef(reg)["X2"]
        
        # short model
        short_reg <- lm(Y ~ X1, data = data)
        short_b1[i] <- coef(short_reg)["X1"]
        
        # compute t-tests
        se_b1 <- summary(reg)$coefficients["X1", "Std. Error"]
        se_b2 <- summary(reg)$coefficients["X2", "Std. Error"]
        t1 <- sqrt(n) * (b1[i] / se_b1)
        t2 <- sqrt(n) * (b2[i] / se_b2)
        t3 <- sqrt(n) * (short_b1[i] / summary(short_reg)$coefficients["X1", "Std. Error"])
        
        test1[i] <- as.integer(t1 < sqrt(log(n)))
        test2[i] <- as.integer(t2 < sqrt(log(n)))
        test3[i] <- as.integer(t3 < sqrt(log(n)))
      }
      
      # store results for current iteration
      iter_result$n <- n
      iter_result$rho <- rho
      iter_result$beta1 <- beta1
      iter_result$beta2 <- beta2
      iter_result$b1_summary <- summary(b1)
      iter_result$b2_summary <- summary(b2)
      iter_result$short_b1_summary <- summary(short_b1)
      iter_result$test1_summary <- summary(test1)
      iter_result$test2_summary <- summary(test2)
      iter_result$test3_summary <- summary(test3)
      
      # append current iteration results to overall results list
      results <- c(results, iter_result)
      
    }
  }
}

sink("output.txt")

cat("My list:\n")
print(results)

sink()
```